# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small + "not a valid month"

Tags: oracle

I am calling a stored procedure from my Java application with 4 in parameters and 6 out parameters. The code is running fine on the production machine giving the proper output.
But when I run the same code on a different system, I am getting some error. Please see the log trace below:

```
**14:48:12,684 ERROR [STDERR] java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at "RFDBTEMP.VEHICLE_TRACKING_2", line 3895
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at "RFDBTEMP.VEHICLE_TRACKING_2", line 4550
ORA-20000: WB_WEIGHT_CAL[no tolerance check for sec wt]V_MWTL_WEIGHT_INDEX :2/ORA-01843: not a valid month
ORA-06512: at "RFDBTEMP.VEHICLE_TRACKING_2", line 2250
ORA-01843: not a valid month
ORA-06512: at line 1
14:48:12,685 ERROR [STDERR]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:439)
14:48:12,686 ERROR [STDERR]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:395)
14:48:12,689 ERROR [STDERR]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:802)
14:48:12,691 ERROR [STDERR]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:436)
14:48:12,693 ERROR [STDERR]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
14:48:12,695 ERROR [STDERR]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:521)
14:48:12,697 ERROR [STDERR]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:202)
14:48:12,701 ERROR [STDERR]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:1005)
14:48:12,703 ERROR [STDERR]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1307)
14:48:12,705 ERROR [STDERR]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3449)
14:48:12,708 ERROR [STDERR]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3530)
14:48:12,709 ERROR [STDERR]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.executeUpdate(OracleCallableStatement.java:4735)
14:48:12,711 ERROR [STDERR]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.
java:1350)**
```

Can there be a possibility that this error be due to system environment settings or some other setting in the system?

**Note: There is no date parameter in the stored procedure but using "SYSTIMESTAMP" inside the procedure. 
I am running my application on JBoss 4 server.**

Comment: We can't diagnose the internals of a package we can't see. (And no, we don't want to see thousands of lines of code!) But it looks like you have an implicit or explicit conversion of a string to a date, which could be failing because of data or different NLS settings; and an exception handler that can't handle a long message, maybe. You need to debug this in your package, or at least look at the reported line numbers.

Comment: Hi Alex! NLS settings are same and we are passing the same data. Also, looked at the line numbers reported in the log but found nothing there. Code is same for both the systems pointing to the same database.

Comment: So what is happening at line 2250? Is it selecting a date from or inserting a date into a table? There's a date manipulation of some kind there or that error wouldn't be raised. Maybe you can add the section of code around that to the question?

Comment: The same Java code and stored procedure is working fine on the production system. The error comes on different machine for same builds. I just want to know if such kind of error can occur due to some system settings or environment settings. Or maybe due to built wars and jars.

Comment: Well, the answer is 'yes'. NLS settings maybe, or server locale (which affects NLS). Otherwise looks like a data issue - though if they are pointing to the same database (and schema) then that seems unlikely. Without the code or any more details of the environment your question is too broad though.

Comment: Pasting the code here seems unlikely as it is thousands of lines of code. One more thing I would like to know though. Can the OJDBC version affect this thing?